# Dart - Encrypt message with public key RSA from string format

Tags: python, dart, rsa

From an api rest built with the Flask framework (Python), I'm getting a `public key` in the `string` format.

According to the site http://studyraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2016/01/sending-rsa-encrypted-message-from.html in python with the `Crypto` lib is done as follows:

```
random_generator = Random.new().read
private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
public_key = private_key.publickey()
publickey = public_key.exportKey() #public key in string format

#Convert string to key
server_public_key = RSA.importKey(publickey)

#Encrypt message and send to server
message = "This is my secret message."
encrypted = server_public_key.encrypt(message, 32)
server.sendall("encrypted_message="+str(encrypted))
```

Is it possible in Dart to get the `public key` in string format and encrypt a message and also send it in the string format?